# Using 'CreateJobObject': on VC++2005 + Win XP SP2

Tags: win32-process

Are job kernel objects only available on Win2000 ?

I am getting compiler errors for:-
    HANDLE hJob = CreateJobObject(NULL, NULL);

error C3861: 'CreateJobObject': identifier not found

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old... but I recently had the same issue until I read the MSDN article a little closer. From the CreateJobObjects MSDN article, "To compile an application that uses this function, define _WIN32_WINNT as 0x0500 or later. For more information, see Using the Windows Headers."

Make sure your "define _WIN32_WINNT..." is before your "#include "